# How do I return a list of bytes in rust-cpython?

Tags: python, rust

I'm trying to return a list of bytes to be used in Python:

```
fn example(_py: Python) -> PyResult<PyList> {
    let result = some_function();

    let elements_raw = vec![];

    for entry in result {
        elements_raw.push(PyBytes::new(_py, &entry.0));
    }

    let x: &[PyBytes] = &elements_raw;
    let py_list = PyList::new(_py, x);


    Ok(py_list)
}
```

However, this line complains because `PyList` requires a `PyObject`:

```
let py_list = PyList::new(_py, x);
```

Is there any way to cast a `PyBytes` into a `PyObject`? Is there some better way to return a list of bytes?

Comment: Have you tried `PyBytes::new(_py, &entry.0).into_object()`? Seems like that is the suggested way to convert to an object from https://dgrunwald.github.io/rust-cpython/doc/cpython/struct.PyBytes.html

Comment: I'm very new to rust, so you'll have to excuse my ignorance. I had found that method, but when I tried to use it, the compiler complained it wasn't available.  Do I have to import something extra?

Comment: You may need to `use cpython::PythonObject` for the trait's methods to be available.